# How to parse html code saved as text?

Tags: python, html, parsing, text-parsing

I have multiple .txt files containing HTML code (HTML code from web pages were copied and saved as .txt).

I want to parse these files as an HTML. Are there any libraries which have similar functionality as requests+bs4 bundle and can treat input from text files as a result of usual web parsing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the html?

Comment: Why exactly can't you use BS4?

Comment: The file extension is irrelevant. No magic happens when you rename a file from .txt to .html. Just open the file (specify an `encoding` with the call to `open()`!), read its content, parse as HTML - for example with beautifulsoup, lxml or pyquery.

Comment: How do I feed a .txt file with HTML code inside of it to BeautidulSoup() then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many of the comments stated it is possible to feed .txt file to BeautifulSoup():

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = 'path/to/file.txt'
with open(path) as f:
    text = f.read()
BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for Beautiful Soup, which can parse and read text from HTML quite easily:

> [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree. It commonly saves programmers hours or days of work.

Comment: I've created these files using requests and bs4.

Comment: Now I want to feed .txt file to BeautifulSoup() as an input, but I don't know how to do it. I'm not sure it's possible right away.